# Have slider value set both by script and in UI using slider handle

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a UI Slider on my Canvas. I am also changing the value of the slider (and therefore position of the handle) from a script. But now the slider cant be move in the UI on runtime anymore. Once I remove the line in my code, it works again. Is there any way to change the value both from the script and in the UI via mouse at runtime, i.e. stop unity from blocking it in the UI when changing it in the script?

Comment: this should be possible - please post the relevant code (and that specific line) that prevents you from moving the slider in the UI and we can help out

Comment: Without seeing your code I'd suggest that your script is setting the slider value every update, thus overriding any changes the user is attempting.  Make sure you only update the slider from script when you absolutely *need* to.

Answer (score 1):

@Immersive was absolutely right. The value was changed within Update() on every frame. Changed it so it only is changed when necessary.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SliderExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    public Text displaySliderValue;

    private float sliderValue;

    private void Update()
    {
        displaySliderValue.text = sliderValue.ToString();
        sliderValue = slider.value;
    }
}
```

[image]